# Mac terminal command to rename with a form of "original file name+currentdate"

Tags: terminal

As it is on the title, I am trying to rename a file to currentdate+original file name.  For example

**yeah.mp3 to yeah_2014_05_19:0131.mp3**

By the way the date form I got simply commanded on terminal "date +%Y_%m_%d:%H%M"

Does anyone have idea?

Comment: Presumably you have more than one file? Is it only MP3 files you want to rename?

Comment: It can be any type of file.  I tried with mv yeah.mp3 to yeah+date  %Y_%m_%d:%H%M.mp3 or yeah+date &%Y_%m_%d:%H%M but I failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

```
original="yeah.mp3"
# Extract extension - the dot and anything after it
extension=${original##*.}
# Extract base - anything before dot
base=${original%.*}
# Formulate date part
datepart=$(date +%Y_%m_%d:%H%M)
# Now build new filename
newname="${base}_${datepart}.${extension}"
echo mv "$original" "$newname"
```

If you want to do a whole load of MP3s for example, you need a loop like this:

```
for original in *.mp3
do
   # Extract extension - the dot and anything after it
   extension=${original##*.}
   # Extract base - anything before dot
   base=${original%.*}
   # Formulate date part
   datepart=$(date +%Y_%m_%d:%H%M)
   # Now build new filename
   newname="${base}_${datepart}.${extension}"
   echo mv "$original" "$newname"
done
```

**Note:**

Remove the word `echo` on the penultimate line if you are happy with what it is going to do - at the moment it does nothing, it only tells you what it is planning to do.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution!  It works!  Wow I didn't know that 6 steps needed to be done than just command "mv original newname".  I am new to shell programming.  Can you recommend any tutorial website or book to learn basic stuffs?

Comment: Actually I was creating a script.  I tried your solution on applescript and I bumped into an error.  That was "Expected expression but found unknown token" on the first line do shell script "original=~/Downloads/recording.mp3".  Would you help me?

Comment: This document tells you pretty much all you would ever need to know about Bash - which, to my mind, is the only shell anyone would ever need. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Comment: Post your Applescript as a new question - there are people on StackOverflow who are better at it than me so you'll get a better answer than if you hide it in the comments if the current question where the formatting is hard to read. You can always add a link to the new question here to be sure I spot it and have a look for you.

Comment: I am bit worried my question can be stupid to someone like who gave this question -1.  But I tried searching web for hours ended up with no solution so I posted it.  I will create another thread for the applescript.  Thank you for the tutorial! I appreciate it!  It was kinda surprise shell can do a loop line by line unlike java :-)